# Blazor navigate to navigating to correct page and immediately back to current page

Tags: button, onclick, blazor

I have a button on an edit page that I want to execute an entity query and then navigate back to the main page.

`<button class="btn" @onclick="(() => UpdateEmpById(Emp))">Save Emp</button>`

The method this button is calling can be seen below...

```
`private async Task UpdateEmpById(Emp emp)
{
    if (emp is null || IsBusy)
    {
        return;
    }

    IsBusy = true;
    try
    {
        using var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

        List<Emp > Temp = await context.Emps
            .Where(x => x.Id == emp.id)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "The employee was modified. Please reload the page";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorMessage = $"Error while saving employee: {ex.Message}";
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/");
}`
```

The page navigates back to "/" and immediately back to the current page and I am unsure why.

I am somewhat new to Blazor and do not know what to try currently.

Comment: This issue was resolved by changing my button to a mudButton. Likely an issue with the syntax on the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Changed button element to a label, fixed. Must have something to do with the button element onclick function and the component I was using, I didn't have the same problem with another component.

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" value="@item.Ecn" @onclick="@(e => Navigate("details" , item.Ecn))">
        Details
</label>
```